# Share raw resources android

Tags: android, android-resources, android-fileprovider, android-sharing

I have .mp3, .mp4 and .jpg files in my raw resources. I want to share those files with social apps. I have tried to set up a file provider for that reason, but it didn't work.

Manifest:

```
<provider
  android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
  android:authorities="com.my.packagename.fileprovider"
  android:exported="false"
  android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/paths" />
</provider>
```

paths.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>

<files-path name="file_path" path="."/>

<external-files-path name="external_path" path="/" />

</paths>
```

This is how I try to share the files (in this case audio):

```
File file = new File(mAudio.getSoundUri().getEncodedPath());
Uri soundUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                getContext(),
                "com.my.packagename.fileprovider",
                file);
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, mAudio.getSoundUri());
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Send"));
```

The `mAudio` object's `getSoundUri()` returns a Uri like this: `android.resource://com.my.packagename/raw/sound.mp3`

When I run this I either don't get any error but the intent doesn't show up and my activity is rebuilt or I get this:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /raw/sound.mp3
```

I have tried to remove /raw from the Uri but I get the same error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /sound.mp3
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this happening?

Resources are files on your development machine. They are not files on the device. There is no filesystem path on the device for a resource, and so `FileProvider` cannot serve them.

Your two main options are:

1. Copy the resources to files (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), then use `FileProvider` to serve the files
2. Write your own `ContentProvider` to serve the raw resources directly (use `getResources()` on a `Context` to get a `Resources` object, and from there you can get an `InputStream` on a raw resource)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply! I am new to android programming, so could you please give me a code sample? Just something scetchy, so that I can see what I have to do.

Comment: @BenceGordos: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v9.0/ContentProvider/Pipe) is a bit old, and it uses assets instead of raw resources, but it illustrates the basic technique. [This is an even older version of the same sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.1/ContentProvider/Pipe), but that happens to be the one covered in [this free older edition](https://commonsware.com/Android/Android-8.1-CC.pdf) of one of my books.